# Using pull requests to update a fork from its upstream parent

Tags: git

I was trying to update my fork from its parent and having trouble, so I asked someone for help and in the course of the conversation the other party stated...

> Pull requests cannot be used to update a fork from it's upstream parent

... which does not make sense to me (especially since that is what I eventually did to sync my fork from its origin).

I'm not asking *how* to sync a fork - that's covered in a few questions already - I don't understand why applying commits via pull request is "bad" when compared to other ways (reparenting my/local to origin/remote and reversing the usual commit path).

If it matters, the branches and relations look like this

```
- origin/remote (has the commits I want)
 - my/remote (where I want to put them - originally forked from origin/remote)
  - my/local (where I dont want to put them - yet. cloned from my/remote)
```

Once my/remote is updated, I would expect to "Sync" or "fetch" my/remote to my/local. I would not expect to follow a path different than the one I used to fork or clone to create them.

Comment: you could just 'skip' modifying your local repo and work everything through the remotes.  `git fetch --all` then `git push origin/branch:my/branch`  This works really well when you're following a branching model where all actual development happens in separate branches and not on your master or develop branches.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use PRs to update a fork from its parent. You can also use PRs to update a fork from another fork. But PRs are not really meant for this. PRs are meant for people that do not have push access to the target or need a code review, so that you can tell "hey I want this merged in" and the receiver can review it and then apply or deny it.

For updating your fork from upstream you should just add the upstream as another remote and then rebase your branches against the upstream branches.

Comment: Doesn't that last part effectively orphan my remote fork, or at least require that I re-create it and re-parent my local to it to preserve the change path?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, but I'm 95% sure the answer is "no". You add upstream as second remote to local, rebase your local branches, then push them to the fork remote that usually is origin.

Comment: I am trying to visualize how the commit should move between branches. Following the initial cloning action would be `origin/remote -|forked|-> my/remote -|cloned|-> my/local`. I think you are saying `origin/remote -|reparent of and pull|-> my/local -|force push|-> my/remote`.

Comment: I still don't really get what you are saying. I think you confuse what branches are. A branch is just a post-it note on a commit that you can at any time peel off and stick to any other commit. There is no hierarchy between branches.

Comment: I understand a branches as independent sets of commits and that the relations I am speaking of are kind of implied. Without that implied hierarchy, how does one manage promotion of changes through testing,release, and maintenance?

Comment: Then you understand it wrongly. A commit is **not** assigned to any branch. A commit is a standalone "thing" that has all parent, grandparent and so on commits in its history. A branch is just a pointer a pointer on one commit. So at a given point in time you can say that commit X is part of the history of branch Y, but it can be part of the history of any amount of branches including zero and you can make a branch pointer point to any other commit at any point in time if you like to, which can cause commit X not being part of branch Y anymore.

Comment: OK - that's counterintuitive but I understand your meaning. Thanks!

Comment: No, it's not, it's Git basics. ;-)